# Regular Expression Statement

Tags: java, regex, text-files, java.util.scanner

I've never been good with regex and I can't seem to get this...

I am trying to match statements along these lines (these are two lines in a text file I'm reading)

```
Lname Fname 12.35 1
Jones Bananaman 7.1 3
```

Currently I am using this for a while statement

```
reader.hasNext("\\w+ \\w+ \\d*\\.\\d{1,2} [0-5]")
```

But it doesn't enter the while statement. 
The program reads the text file just fine when I remove the while.
The code segment is this:

```
private void initializeFileData(){
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(openedPath);

        while(reader.hasNext("\\w+ \\w+ \\d*\\.\\d{1,2} [0-5]")){
            employeeInfo.add(new EmployeeFile(reader.next(), reader.next(), reader.nextDouble(), reader.nextInt(), new employeeRemove()));
        }
        for(EmployeeFile element: employeeInfo){
            output.add(element);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `\s` character class for the spaces between words:

```
while(reader.hasNext("\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\d*\\.\\d{1,2}\\s[0-5]"))
```

**Update:**

According to the javadoc for the `Scanner` class, by default it splits it's tokens using whitespace. You can change the delimiter it uses with the `useDelimiter(String pattern)` method of `Scanner`.

```
private void initializeFileData(){
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(openedPath).useDelimiter("\\n");
        ...
        while(reader.hasNext("\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\d*\\.\\d{1,2}\\s[0-5]")){
        ...
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: I tried that earlier and it didn't work, I also used your code to double check with no luck. I changed it back because I'm fairly sure it should work with \\s or ' '. Regardless, still not working.

Comment: hmmm... could it be then that you need to use a different delimiter for the scanner so that it splits tokens by newline instead of whitespace? `Scanner reader = new Scanner(openedPath).useDelimiter("\\n");`

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see (And correct me if I'm wrong, because regex always seems to trick my brain :p), you're not handling the spaces correctly. You need to use \s, not just the standard ' ' character

EDIT: Sorry, \s. Someone else beat me to it :p

Answer (score 0):

Actually

```
\w+
```

is going to catch `[Lname, Fname, 12, 35, 1]` for `Lname Fname 12.35 1`. So you can just store `reader.nextLine()` and then extract all regex matches from there. From there, you can abstract it a bit for instance by :

```
class EmployeeFile {

 .....

     public EmployeeFile(String firstName, String lastName,
                         Double firstDouble, int firstInt,
                         EmployeeRemove er){
          .....
     }

     public EmployeeFile(String line) {
        //TODO : extract all the required info from the string array
        //       instead of doing it while reading at the same time. 
        //       Keep input parsing separate from input reading.
        //       Turn this into a string array using the regex pattern 
        //       mentioned above

     }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created my own version, without files and the last loop, that goes like that:

```
private static void initializeFileData() {
        String[] testStrings = {"Lname Fname 12.35 1", "Jones Bananaman 7.1 3"};
        Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\d*\\.\\d{1,2})\\s+([0-5])");
        for (String s : testStrings) {
            Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(s);
            if (myMatcher.groupCount() == 4) {
                String lastName = myMatcher.group(1);
                String firstName = myMatcher.group(2);
                double firstValue = Double.parseDouble(myMatcher.group(3) );
                int secondValue = Integer.parseInt(myMatcher.group(4));                
                //employeeInfo.add(new EmployeeFile(lastName, firstName, firstValue, secondValue, new employeeRemove()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice that I removed the slash before the dot (you want a dot, not any character) and inserted the parenthesis, in order to create the groups.

I hope it helps.